# ASP.NET MVC : Custom Sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement custom sorting in my small asp.net mvc application. Well there are lots of plgins available. But this time I want to do on my own.

**Here is My Table Header:**

```
 <tr>
    <th>
        S.No.
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("UrlTitle", "Index", new { SortOrder = ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc"? "Desc":"Asc"), SortBy = "UrlTitle" })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UrlDesc)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tbl_Category.CategoryName)
    </th>
</tr>
```

**And this is the action:**

```
public ActionResult Index(String SortOrder, String SortBy)
    {
        ViewBag.SortOrder = SortOrder;
        ViewBag.SortBy = SortBy;

        var model = ObjBs.GetAll().Where(x=>x.IsApproved == "A");
        switch(SortOrder)
        {
            case "Asc":
                model = model.OrderBy(x => x.UrlTitle);
                break;
            case "Desc":
                model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrlTitle);
                break;
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Currently, I can sort by UrlTitle and there is no problem with it. But If I want to sort by other columns too, I wrote something like this:

```
switch(SortBy)
        {
            case "UrlTitle":
                switch(SortOrder)
                {
                    case "Asc":
                        model = model.OrderBy(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    case "Desc":
                        model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case "Category":
                switch (SortOrder)
                {
                    case "Asc":
                        model = model.OrderBy(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    case "Desc":
                        model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case "URL":
                switch (SortOrder)
                {
                    case "Asc":
                        model = model.OrderBy(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    case "Desc":
                        model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UrlTitle);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Since I could Pass the column name through parameter, instead of writing nested switch, Can't I do something like this :

```
    model = model.OrderBy(x => x.SortBy); Or, model = model.OrderBy(SortBy);
```

Well I thought that when the program runs the value of the SortBy is gonna be the columnName. But it doesn't seems to work.

I just don't want to write the similar code repeatedly. How can I minimize it or make it even better?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the reflection route, you should be able to use [dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) for your queries.